# Callable element after .remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to remove element after exit from jQuery dialog. I use `.remove()` functions but this element is not calable after `.remove()` executes.

How to "destroy" object in js and open possibility to call it again without refresh parent element.

```
 $('.createAuthor').click(function () {
        dialog = $('#form').dialog({
            title: 'Add new author',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: true,
            close: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).dialog("destroy");
                dialog.remove();
            }
        });
        $('.submitAuthors').one('click', function () {
            var fname = $('#fname').val(),
                lname = $('#lname').val(),
                email = $('#email').val();
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "/sci-profile/authors/approval",
                data: {
                    fname: fname,
                    lname: lname,
                    email: email,
                    articleId: articleId
                },
                success: function(response)
                {
                    $( "#authors tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + fname + ' ' + lname + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + email + "</td>" +
                            "</tr>" );
                    $('#form')[0].reset();
                    dialog.dialog('destroy');
                }

            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: `dialog.detach();`?!

Comment: @Tushar no help from null, If I open and close 4 times the dialog. then I click submit code will execute 4 time ajax even I have use .one() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh, how bad mistake I had made. I had bind function block once per `.createAuthor` click even I had use .one()

.one() is suppose to limit execute code **inner** function but not **outer**.

```
$('.createAuthor').click(function () {
        dialog = $('#form').dialog({
            title: 'Add new author',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: true,
            close: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).dialog("destroy");
                dialog.remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

I only need to use function bellow **separate**.

```
    $('.submitAuthors').one('click', function () {
        var fname = $('#fname').val(),
            lname = $('#lname').val(),
            email = $('#email').val();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/sci-profile/authors/approval",
            data: {
                fname: fname,
                lname: lname,
                email: email,
                articleId: articleId
            },
            success: function(response)
            {
                $( "#authors tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + fname + ' ' + lname + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + email + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>" );
                $('#form')[0].reset();
                dialog.dialog('destroy');
            }

        });
    });
```

I must notice that `$('.submitAuthors')` is in *`$('#form')`*

```
<form id="form" style="display: none">
            <label for="name">First name</label><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <label for="name">Last Name</label><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <label for="email">Email</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <span class="submitAuthors">Submit</span>
</form>
```